# Insert multiple enteries into one db column

Tags: php, database, string, database-design

How to insert names of multiple files into one column? File names will be stored in the same column, seperated by a comma.

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fupload"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$name)) {
    $count++;
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO product(id, product_name, image) VALUES ('$id','$_POST[productname]', '$name')");}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though @Ehsan-Abd answered this question with the most recommended way which is using a seperate table, if you still want to use your own method, you need to process all the input and concatenate the filenames, then, use a single `INSERT` to insert the final string.

`$names='';
 foreach($filename as $name){
    $names.=','.$name;
 }
 if($names!=''){
    $names=substr($names,1);
 }`

---

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO product(id, product_name, image) VALUES ('$id','$_POST[productname]', '$names')");}
```

Comment: thank you, it works! but the first data always store comma (,) like this = ", photo1.jpg, photo2.jpg, photo3.jpg" how to remove the first comma

Comment: I updated the answer to fix that. You may need to practice php more with the help of the php.net documentation. I highly recommend you keep it open in a browser window while you are coding.

Comment: @Tom you may use `implode` like `$names_with_comma_between = implode(',', $filenames);`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do that you'd better create a new table like `uploaded_files` and link it with the `product` table by a `foreign key` such as `product_id`. Including all the files paths in one column is not a good practice.

Comment: yes i think so. but i need different way, path is'nt stored into column, filename only